# Как запустить сервер laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, сервер, composer

Как запустить laravel? Если composer установлен, проект создан, а при команде
php artisan serve
Выдает такую ошибку

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\Nikits\Desktop\laravel\test/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open 

stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Nikits\Desktop\laravel\test\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Nikits\Desktop\laravel\test/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\Nikits\Desktop\laravel\test\artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\Nikits\Desktop\laravel\test\artisan on line 18
```

Comment: Прочитайте инструкцию по установке Laravel, там есть пункт об установке composer зависимостей.

Comment: Делал `composer install` ?

Comment: Problem1
    -laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Comment: выдает такую ошибку

Comment: я делал php ini но не понимаю что там надо делать и что регистрировать, вернее там вообще простовыводится этот текст

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить эту строчку в php.ini

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```